# Equivalent of stream in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

what is the equivalent of this code to kotlin?

```
stack = stack.stream()
    .map(e -> // some code here)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));
```

I currently have this one

```
stack = stack.withIndex()
    .map { (i, v) -> {
        // some code here
    }}
    .toCollection(ArrayDeque::new)
```

I cannot resolve the ArrayDeque::new part. How to do this in kotlin?

**Update**

this is my original code and im working for a stack using ArrayDeque, I need to update the stack on specific index from 0. Now I got an error that I cannot assign the code suggested below to the stack

```
var stack = ArrayDeque<Long>()

for (op in operations){
    val split = op.split(' ')
    when (split[0]) {
        "push" -> {
            stack.push(split[1].toLong())
        }
        "pop" -> {
            stack.pop()
        }
        else -> {
            stack = stack.withIndex()
                .map { (i, v) -> {
                    if (i < split[1].toInt())
                        v + split[2].toLong()
                    else
                        v
                }}
                .toCollection(ArrayDeque())
        }
    }

    if (stack.isEmpty()){
        println("EMPTY")
    } else {
        println(stack.peekFirst()!!)
    }
}
```

Here's the error

`error: type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is ArrayDeque<Long> but ArrayDeque<Long> was expected`

Comment: extra brackets after `.map { (i, v) ->`. `.map { (i, v) -> if ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of:

```
stack.withIndex()
  .map { (i, v) -> {  /* code */  }}
   .toCollection(ArrayDeque())
```

OR

```
stack.withIndex()
    .mapTo(ArrayDeque()) { (i, v) -> { /* code  */ } }
```

I'd lean for the second if you just have single `map` but if you have a longer chain I'd go for `toCollection`.